# Water won't pass through channel, and how to make a rotor stay on its place while it spins?

Tags: animation

I am a Dutch engineering student, normally I use Inventor, solidworks or autocad to make 3D designs.

Now I have to make some sort of a water turbine and I gotta simulate the spinning of the rotor itself. Well, now I haven't used Blender yet, I just downloaded it and I am struggling with everything.

I want to make some sort of a channel to let the water flow through on the rotor. But it got blocked by some sort of an invisible wall and I don't know how to fix it or what I've done wrong...

Here's the link to a [video](https://i.imgur.com/xXKuwSI.mp4), which makes it more clear.

Also I would like to know how to fixate a rotor and let it spin because of the water.

Please let me know how to fix this and what causes the problem. And how I can make the rotor work.

Here is the .blend file itself:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to BSE. Please remember that this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, so make sure your question sticks to the point and is as clear as possible. Regarding the question, it would be beneficial if you could provide the blend file at https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ - simulations are tricky to debug sometimes.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5593" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5593/)

Comment: sorry, here you go. @aliasguru

Comment: @DaanKouwen Your channel object has extra geometry that isn't being shown. some duplicate vertices but also faces right before the turbine. that's causing the flow to stop until it pours over the sides. personally i'd recommend just recreating that from scratch using only inset/extrude and move tools.

Comment: @Ratt thanks for your reply! Are there any video's on how to work like that? this is the only way I know how to create something, I know I am a idiot. Sorry for that...

Comment: @DaanKouwen Concept example [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=60uwdZsApyQ) essentially you never want to have any faces, segments, or vertices on top of each other when modelling.

Answer (score 0):

From just looking at the image without examining the file, it looks like you didn't make your water domain big enough. Is the water domain object covering the entire channel unit?

Comment: Yes it is. The problem probbebly lies in with the fact that I just deleted a face instead of creating a complete new structure. Thanks for the reply!